# I can't control how the app opens the notification message with firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

[image]

FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp is not working

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  debugPrint("CLICKED!");
  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
  AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;

  debugPrint("id: ${notification?.body}");

  if (android != null && notification != null) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NotificationScreen()),
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Please provide what error you are getting, if any.

Try to be more descriptive

Comment: Have you add  "click_action": 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK' to the data payload

Comment: Please copy & paste your code, instead of uploading its picture.

Comment: @MKarimi uploaded